# Как решить задачу на поразрядную конъюнкцию

Tags: python, python-3.x

Обозначим через m & n поразрядную конъюнкцию неотрицательных целых чисел m и n.

Так, например, 14 & 5 = 1110 & 0101 = 0100 = 4. Для какого наименьшего неотрицательного целого числа А формула

x & 29 ≠ 0 → (x & 17 = 0 → x & А ≠ 0)

тождественно истинна (т. е. принимает значение 1 при любом неотрицательном целом значении переменной x)?

---

Написал функцию этой самой конъюнкции и импликации, затем функцию перебора всех x до 100 при каком либо A, которая вернет False, если хоть одно значение x не прошло.

```
def conc(n, k):
    n = bin(n)[2:]
    k = bin(k)[2:]
    s = ''
    if len(n) != len(k):
        if len(n) > len(k):
            k = '0' * (len(n) - len(k)) + k
        else:
            n = '0' * (len(k) - len(n)) + n
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] == k[i]:
            s += '1'
        else:
            s += '0'
    return int(s,2)

def impl(x, y): return not x or y

def F(A):
    for x in range(10000):
        if not impl(conc(x, 29) != 0, impl(conc(x, 17) == 0,conc(x, A) != 0)):
            return False
    return A


for i in range(100):
    if F(i)!=False: print(i)
```

Функции конъюнкции и импликации вроде правильные, но при выполнении программы выдает все значения от 2 до 100. В ответе к задаче число 12. Где я ошибся, уже часа 2 бьюсь над задачей, но не могу понять??

Comment: А что означает `→` ?

Comment: Это импликация вроде как, т.е. x»y==not x or y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if n[i] == k[i]:
        s += '1'
    else:
        s += '0'
```

Это не `побитовое И` (конъюнкция), надо чтобы оба разряда не только были равны между собой, но и равны `1` при этом, так что правильно будет так:

```
    if n[i] == k[i] == '1':
        s += '1'
    else:
        s += '0'
```

После этого исправления вывод кода такой:

```
12
13
14
15
28
29
30
31
44
45
46
47
60
61
62
63
76
77
78
79
92
93
94
95
```